# LessCss w/ dotLess mixin issue for IE gradient filter

Tags: less, mixins, css, dotless

I have the following less mixin defined:

```
.TopDownActiveGradient(@s1, @s2){ 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @s1 0%, @s2 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,@s1), color-stop(100%,@s2)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @s1 0%, @s2 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, @s1 0%, @s2 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, @s1 0%, @s2 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, @s1 0%, @s2 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@{s1}', endColorstr='@{s2}'); /* IE6-8 */}
```

And it is used like this:

`.TopDownActiveGradient(#f7f7f7, #fffffe);`

Now, it works fine when the colors I enter cannot be reduced to a shorthand version (e.g. #dadada), meaning if I use #ffffff as a color which can be converted to #fff, it **won't work** as the filter for Ie6-8 expects a full color hex value.

This issue only happens **when the minify option is turned on**. if I choose not to minify, #ffffff is turned into 'white', which works fine.

My question will be how can I stop the color hex code minification in my mixin? Or is there any way around this limitation?

I have tried a lot of things but none worked.

Comment: try a different compressor? Perhaps `--yui-compress` might work.

Answer (score 2):

For 8 char hex, this has been fixed in dotless main - https://github.com/dotless/dotless/commit/52ba9a4ccf4e9a895d557f01112ab4c7f4cad8a7

This is in the current release.

If you need 6 char hex you could try using interpolation

~"@col"

Though, I'm not sure it will work.

Comment: thanks Luke. I want to vote up but don't have enough reputation yet. I am not familiar with dotless main on github... is there a way to download it now or I have to wait? I couldn't find anything other than 1.3.0.5. And help me understand this: does it mean that from 1.3.1 on colors won't be compressed? or is it for IE? I can't seem to understand the logic from the page you show me. By the way I got my dotless installation from Nuget.

Comment: github has the source code on it.. you'd have to download and compile. I do a build and put it on github and Nuget. the change just stops ie colours(8 hex chars) being compressed.

Comment: Then the solution is not going to help my problem. My issue is with #ffffff being converted into #fff which is not compatible with IE's filter which expects full 6 hex chars.